# Kotlin Annotation Processor not working? What am I missing?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, kapt

Recently I've been trying to make a annotation processor through Kotlin but I can't seem to get it to work. Everything compiles and I don't get any errors but when I check the contents of my jar file I don't see the resource I'm trying to create.

I've tried everything for hours and I'm really stuck so just looking for help :/ I do have one random class annotated to see if it would work but no luck.

The annotation class

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class TestAnnotation
```

The processor class

```
@AutoService(TestAnnotation::class)
class TestAnnotationProcessor : AbstractProcessor() {
    override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>, environment: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {        
        this.processingEnv.filer.createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "", "test.txt")

        return true
    }

    override fun getSupportedSourceVersion() = SourceVersion.RELEASE_8

    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes() = setOf(TestAnnotation::class.java.canonicalName)
}
```

My build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"

    kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.50"

    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "5.1.0"
}

group = "com.example.test"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.1")

    implementation("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6")
    kapt("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    dependencies {
        exclude(dependency("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your custom annotation processor to work, you will have to use it in your build script dependencies

```
dependencies {
    kapt project(':processor-module') // or what ever your processor's module is named.
    //OR
    kapt 'gourp:artifact:version' // if your processor is published into a maven repository.
}
```